# Eigenvectors when the eigenvalue if the norm of the matrix.

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, normed-spaces

Does there exist  $x$ such that $\|Ax\|=\|A\|$, where
$$\|A\|=\sup\{|d|:d\text{ is eigenvalue of of the symmetric matrix $A$}\}$$
Why does it suffice to find an eigenvector of the eigenvalue I found, or does it not?

Comment: Yes, if $d$ is such that $|d|=\|A\|$, then by definition there exists a $d$ eigenvector $x$, that is, $Ax=dx$, so $\|Ax\| = |d|\|x\|=|d|=\|A\|$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you want to know if there exists $x$ with $\|x\|=1$ and $\|A(x)\|=\|A\|$. A symmetric matrix is diagonalizable, so if $d$ is the bigger value, there exists $x$ such that $A(x)=dx$. You can take $x$ such that $\|x\|=1$.